# Unix - Finding names with egrep

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am trying to come up with an egrep script to distinguish names--words  which are written with an initial upper case, such as countries, names of people etc--in a set of txt files. I want to ignore numbers and select all the uppercase words, only the word, excluding those that are at the beginning of a sentence (so, following '. ') Other recommended patterns are also welcome

An example input can be:

> General public interest in whether there is water on Mars has been a perennial interest since the the 1800s. In 1877, when Mars approached Earth almost as closely as it could (still a rather distant 56 million kilometres away), the Italian astronomer Giovanni Schiaparelli observed the Red Planet. He made maps of the surface features that he saw, including what looked like a network of channels.

output would be:

```
Earth
Giovanni
Italian
Mars
Planet
Red
Schiparelli
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us an example input and your desired output. What do you mean by "proper" names? Do you mean given names ("proper name" does not mean the same in English as it does in Spanish or French). Is it enough to detect all UPPER CASE words? Or do you need `Foo` but not `FOO` or `foo`?

Comment: If a line ends with `.`, and the first word on the next line is capitalized, do you want that word to be output? If the line ends with `.` followed by some spaces, and there are one or more blank lines following that, followed by a line whose first word is capitalized, do you want that word to be output?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes that or any other punctuation case should be excluded

Comment: If that's the case, I suspect a multi-line pattern like this can't be detected with egrep unless there's some preprocessing done to join lines together. Are you allowed to use perl or awk?

Comment: Only egrep, It is possible to extend commands by adding + and |egrep again. Or I can make a new file with the results to make several filters and eventually sort them and have single instances (sort, uniq)?

Comment: @patimadison - this last thing you say doesnt make sense. if you can only use `egrep`, then how is it `sort` and `uniq` are candidates?

Comment: I am following the guidelines of "egrep for linguists" there it doesn't make a distinction for uniq sort or tr?

Comment: ok. in the first place, you cant ever do this with `egrep`. some newer `grep`s - like GNU `grep` - can do `-o` and output only matching words, but any `egrep` that does so is only a symlink for backwards compatibility's sake, as far as i know. `grep -E` is the standard syntax these days. and secondly, at least for the reasons already mentioned, youre going to need an editing tool, not just a searching tool.

Comment: I took a stab at it with `sed` and `tr` - which kind of worked - but what happens when a proper noun starts a sentence? *Some dumb sentence. Pati likes language.* I think the bottom line here is that you're going to need a dictionary.

Comment: You can't really exclude those cases with this requirements, hence those cases will be ignored. I am trying to make an output txt file with all the uppercases but I want to include in the result the part of the string prior to the word so that afterwards I can filter the cases from that file that don't start directly with an uppercase. I want a query to match the full word and the two characters before it but not the whole line and would print this in separate lines, like with -o. Any idea?

Comment: @patimadison please explain all your requirements in the actual question. Is there any reason you are forced to use `grep-E` (`egrep` is deprecated)? If you also want the two characters before the match, [edit] your question and tell us so.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to i) remove all newlines so that the entire thing is one long string and you can avoid matching the first words of sentences whose preceding full stop was on the previous line and ii) find all words whose first letter is a capital and whose preceding character is not one of `.`,`?`,`!`. For example:

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' < file | grep -Po '(?<![.!?]) \K[A-Z]\w+' 
Mars
Mars
Earth
Italian
Giovanni
Schiaparelli
Red
Planet
```

And to remove duplicate entries:

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' < file  | grep -Po '(?<![.!?]) \K[A-Z]\w+' | sort -u
Earth
Giovanni
Italian
Mars
Planet
Red
Schiaparelli
```

The `tr` replaces newlines with spaces. The `-P` switch turns on Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) support which gives us the advanced features we're using. The `-o` means "print only the matching portion of the line".

The regular expression uses a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?>!foo)`) to make sure we only match anything except a `?`,`!` or `.`, then a space, then a capital letter `[A-Z]` followed by one or more word characters.

Note that this will fail if:

- a name is the first word of the file;
- a name is the first word of a sentence;
- you have compound names like María de Quinto, it will match `María` and `Quinto` but skip the `de`.

---

If your `grep` doesn't support the `-P` or `-o` options, you can use Perl instead:

```
perl -0lne 'print join "\n",(/(?<![.!?]) \K[A-Z]\w+/g)' file | sort -u
```

Comment: Thanks! @terdon the former answer gave some errors, my grep supports -o but apparently not -P. The last query with perl worked perfectly, although it is not grep I got exactly the right output :)

Comment: @patimadison glad it helps. If this solves your issue, please take a moment and [mark it as accepted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (but fell free to wait for other answers, if you like). As for `-P`, this sort of thing is why you should _always_ mention your operating system. I guess you're using OSX which doesn't support `-P`. That's the kind of detail you really should mention next time.

Comment: thanks for the tip! :) I will keep it in mind for next time!